# Output list of comma separated strings in R

Tags: r, arrays, string

I was wondering if there is a quick way to do the following in R:

Given a list input of say:

```
input = c(1234,2394,2212)
```

which are all numeric say, is it possible to get an output of:

```
output = ('1234', '2394', '2212')
```

i.e., printed to the R console as a list of strings with single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
as.character(input)
```

---

Or if we need a single string

```
out <- toString(sQuote(as.character(input), FALSE))
cat(out, "\n")
'1234', '2394', '2212'
```